# SQL - Operator LIKE returns '%' or null

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-like

I needs to create a query to the database that will filter the results like this:

```
    [ProjectNumber] LIKE
        CASE WHEN IsNull(@ProjectId,'') = '' THEN
        '%'
        ELSE
        @ProjectId + '%'
        END
    AND
    [CountryCode] LIKE
        CASE WHEN IsNull(@Country,'') = '' THEN
        '%'
        ELSE
        @Country + '%'
        END
```

When both variables have value everything works, but if @Country is null then this query returns all results for which in the CountryCode column there is a value, and I need to return all (even if the field is Null). Anyone know how to write this query in case of null variable that returned all the fields (fields with value and fields with null)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `CASE ... WHEN ...` and `ISNULL` function, you can do this:

```
...
(@ProjectId IS NULL OR [ProjectNumber] LIKE @ProjectId + '%')
AND
(@Country IS NULL OR [CountryCode] LIKE @Country + '%')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply use

```
ProjectNumber LIKE IsNull(@ProjectId,'') + '%' AND 
CountryCode LIKE IsNull(@Country,'') + '%'
```

Comment: Exactly, the ISNULL() function already performs the check on the ProjectId and Country and then returns either the value or the empty string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the case statement. Try the below  :

```
ISNULL([ProjectNumber],'') LIKE IsNull(@ProjectId,'')+'%'
AND
ISNULL([CountryCode],'') LIKE ISNULL(@Country,'') + '%'
```

because both your case statements will give the same effect above.